# Example of immersed submanifold that intersects itself non-transversally

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold, transversality

Two submanifolds are said to intersect transversally if, along its intersection, the tangent spaces of the two submanifolds span the tangent space of the ambient space.

Can a hypersurface immersed in $R^n$ intersect itself non-transversally? I ask because all the examples I see of immersed surfaces intersecting themselves seem to be transversal intersections and I'm finding it hard to come up with an example of my own where the intersection is non-transversal (I'm relatively new to this way of thinking).

Comment: Have you tried $n=2$? (The same idea will work in higher dimensions, of course.) But it's easy to draw lots of curves!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm thinking of an immersed circle that touches itself exactly at one point (looks like a dumbbell). Is this a good example?

Comment: That'll work fine. So would a parabola that turns and returns tangent at one point.

Comment: Think of the usual parameterization of the unit circle by the ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: @Moishe: That was sneaky :P